# How to store value as an array with UseState in React form when submit?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a form in React, I am able to store the categories in an array but whenever the user types something it behaves differently.

I am passing product objects to the backend where categories are array. How should I store this value in the array when the user submits all forms without affecting UX? Can I move this logic to `submitHandler` function?

[image: This is how it looks like when I type Man for instance]

Here is what I tried.

```
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0)

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(createProduct({
      title,
      desc,
      img,
      categories,
      size,
      price,
      countInStock
    }))
  };

<Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <Form.Group controlId="categories">
            <Form.Label>Categories</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="categories"
              placeholder="Enter categories"
              value={categories}
              onChange={(e) => setCategories(category => [...category, e.target.value])}
            ></Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
    
          <Container className="">
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <Button type="submit" variant="primary" className="my-2">
                  Create
                </Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </Form>
      )}
      </FormContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think currently you are using `setCategory` in a way which would create a list of the previous value and the **current value as a string**.

To get the current input value (`e.target.value`) as an array you could do `e.target.value.split(",")`, which would give the array `['M','Ma','M','Man']`, and then you can just spread it as you did with `category`.

This would result in `onChange` to look like this:

`onChange={e => setCategories(category => [...category, ...e.target.value.split(",")}`